# C# Printing ArrayList Containing Multiple Values

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm new to ArrayList. As far as I know ArrayLists each element(?) can contain multiple values (excuse me for not using the correct terminology).

Now, here's the problem, If I make an ArrayList where each element contains  only one value, I can easily print it, however as in the example below, if I attempt to make an ArrayList where each element contains multiple values - I cannot print the values of each element in the ArrayList. 
If I try to use foreach or for loop using Console.Writeline(list[i]); all I get is the namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
class Register
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;

    public void RegisterData()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your name: "); name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your surname: "); surname= Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void PrintData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name + " Surname: " + surname);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        Register temp = new Register();

        temp.RegisterData();

        list.Add(temp);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            // How can I use the PrintData (without modifying it) method to print the ArrayList values?
        }
    }
}
}
```

How could I be able to print the values of the ArrayList without using the PrintData Method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your comment in the code and the question you have asked below the code are conflicting, you may want to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList` is .NET 1.1 stuff. You should use `List` instead. It's generic and superior over `ArrayList`.

So you define your list like

```
List<Register> list = new List<Register>();

...

list.Add(temp);
```

And in the foreach loop, you can access the properties of your `Register` class. You can do that with `ArrayList`, too. But then you need casts. Why not use List then... Looks much cleaner:

```
foreach (Register register in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + register.name + " Surname: " + register.surname);
    // or
    // register.PrintData();
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to use the `PrintData` method so just throw that in the foreach loop instead

Comment: Oh, must have over-looked that. Thanks!

Comment: Well now that I re-read it, his comment within the code says "// How can I use the PrintData (without modifying it) method to print the ArrayList values?" but his question below the code conflicts with that.... I think its just a typo though.  Good answer

Answer (score 2):

You're adding an instance of Register to your ArrayList.  When you index into it, `list[i]`, that returns this instance.

When you attempt to print this instance, you are in fact calling this method: [Console.WriteLine(object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx), as it is the best fit.  This method needs to get a string from your object, so it calls `ToString()` on it.

The default implementation of `ToString()` returns the namespace and type name for the current object. In this case, "WhateverYourBloodyNamespaceIs.Register".

Now you know you have an object of type Register, you can get `name` and `surname` from it, format them properly and write *those* to the console.  You've got a `PrintData` method, use it.

ArrayList isn't generic, so you must cast from `object` back to `Register`.  Or, be a big boy and use `List<Register>` instead of that 2002 ArrayList crap.

Whoever told you to use an ArrayList is playing tricks on you.

You need to pick up a copy of CLR Via C#.  Skip the first two chapters.  Start reading.  Go.  Run.  I'm not joking.

Answer (score 1):

Override ToString() method in your Register class, then you pass the 'temp' variable to Console.WriteLine() method.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I had no idea about ArrayLists being that outdated. Definitely will use List instead.